# RSelenium, Can't start server

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I'm trying to use RSelenium for web-scraping purposes behind a login and I can't get the server to run.

Current result:

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4444,
                      browserName = "firefox") 
remDr$open()
# [1] "Connecting to remote server"
```

> ```
> Error:     Summary: UnknownError
>    Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>    class: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException
> ```

I've tried running the server myself by downloading and trying to open it (nothing happens).

Comment: As an aside, Please add a meaningful title. They help your post get more views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tough one and stopped me for a couple of days when I could search on it. In the end I uninstalled Firefox and installed version 37.0 while also disabling the update service. That fixed it for me and RSelenium works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code first then it should work:

```
RSelenium::checkForServer()
```

This line of code installs the selenium server which you need for running RSelenium commands.

Comment: Yup, I tried that first and still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
rD <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="firefox")
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox") 
mybrowser$open()
```

RSelenium has problems to establish serwer at the begginig on respective port. Subsequently we are telling which driver should be used.